# USB to USB file transfer using Raspberry Pi?

Tags: usb

Is it possible at all?

I want to make a device to explore the files inside USB flash drive and do some jobs (like copy them to another flash drive fast or renaming the files or folders)

I googled a lot but I couldn't find any answer.

Several modules with different usages but none of them can transfer files to each other on high speed.

Can I use any kind of Raspberry to do this job very fast?

Comment: If you wan't to copy files from a USB stick to another with an Raspberry Pi, it's doable. The USB port on Raspberry Pi is a USB 2.0 there is alternatives like, Banana Pi, Orange Pi, Beagle Bone that have USB 3.0 that is faster.

Comment: which one should i use??Which one of raspberry pi s have 2 usb ports???

Comment: There are many different Raspberry Pi's like: A, B, B+, 2, 3, Zero, Zero W. So it depends, ref.: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raspberry_Pi

Comment: Very fast is hard on older Raspberries as all the USB-ports share a single USB 2.0 bus.  So copying speed is limited by the bandwidth of the bus.

Answer (score 0):

Any rpi can do it with a usb hub extension. You just open terminal and cp from one drive to another. Rpi3 can do it out of box, the zero cannot

Answer (score 0):

If you want to copy files from a USB stick to another with an Raspberry Pi, it's doable.

The USB port on Raspberry Pi is a USB 2.0 there is alternatives like, Banana Pi, Orange Pi, Beagle Bone that have USB 3.0 that is faster.